# CountVectorizer returns 1x1 sparse matrix

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

My X_train data is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvRgQ.png)

The code I am using is

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X_count = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
```

The shape of X_count is (1 x 1).

I am expecting  the returned feature matrix to be of shape (n*rows, n*features).  I am not able to figure out what I am missing.  Any help is appreciated.